# Frequency to voltage circuit with LM339 in KORG MS-20 synthesizer

Tags: comparator

This is an extract from KORG MS-20 synth schematic. The purpose of the circuit is to convert frequency into voltage (with Hz/volt implementation, double the pitch and double the voltage).

The part I'm interested in is the one marked in red. I can see the first comparator is used as an amplifier and the following one is a zero-crossing detector but, from there on I don't really understand what's happening.

Could someone explain the circuit and how it performs frequency to voltage conversion?

[image]
[image]

You can find the whole schematic [here](http://www.synfo.nl/servicemanuals/Korg/MS-20_SERVICE_MANUAL.pdf), the circuit is at the end of page 5.

Comment: I find the rightmost comparator weird. Presumably it is unused and they hooked it up like that not to get floating inputs, but why did they even connect R26 as a pullup? Or is there a mistake in the schematic? If you don't see it, its two inputs are hardwired straight to the positive and negative rail, and there's a pullup to the positive rail. Then it's used in the feedback, but shouldn't make any difference at all...

Comment: @ pipe Yeah. R25 could be tied to V- with the same effect, unless this is OUTPUT_DRIVE_STRENGTH compensation.

Comment: As a matter of interest, what is an f/V used for? I'm familiar with the 1 V/octave standard of analog synths and how this was generally used to control the VCOs for the primary pitch control. Since that control signal is generally available it seems unnecessary to generate it again. Was f to V used for external inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of f/V converter is just like a tachometer.  Create a fixed voltage pulse amplitude and width (1 shot) of current to charge a capacitor then the output voltage is proportional to the pulse rate.

In this case, the sine is converted to a square wave with hysteresis then to simulate full wave rectified or frequency doubled using an inverting OA to drive a diode with the input with another diode to a transistor current source and Cap on the collector. So in effect, 2f/V but the scaling of DC can be done after.

[image]

There are a few other details I omitted in the last two stages, but basically unity gain with an attenuator tap to R27,R32 for amplitude control.

Answer (score 0):

the red part produces a series of fixed width pulses at twice the input frequency. these pulses are cleaned up by the 4069 and then converted to voltage in low-pass filter at the end,

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Going by deduction that would explain the presence of 4069 buffers. But i don't see how a train of pulses can be turned into proportional DC voltage by low pass filtering, unless pulses peak amplitude is frequency dependant.

Comment: pulses are all same length, with higher frequenct more pulses so more time spent high, so volts,  it's like PWM only the width of the low part is variable but the high part is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The left hand 2 comparators produce TWO pulses per input sinwave, with each pulse at the zero crossings. Those pulses are used to turn on Tr2 and discharge C2.

The level-translation circuit R27/R32 converts the +- 15? volt comparator output to something more compatible with the logic inverters (used as 5nanoSecond amplifiers) to produce consistent_area (constant_charge) pulses into the FET opamp which provides active low-pass filtering.

Notice the time constant of the FET opamp is adjustable, controlled by the "low cut" adjustment in prior circuits.

Comment: I think you need to analyse the fuller circuit to explain how it reconstructs a DC signal representing frequency.

Comment: Ok, so i assume the circuit detects time between pulses happening at zero-crossing and discharge C2 proportionally.

Comment: there's no way it partially discharges that capacior, beta is unconstrained, it must be being used as a switch,

Comment: @ Jasen II agree with you.